# Displaying string text in flex

Tags: string, flash, apache-flex

relatively new to flex. I am trying to display text from a string on a view. I would like if it wasn't in a list/button/text area but just text. I know how to display text but I'm not sure how you would take text from a string and put it to text on the screen. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess I Don't really understand what you want to do.  Have you tried a Label?  Or I suppose you can skin a TextInput to remove the border and make the field non-editable using the editable property. Since you are new; I Suggest you start by reading some documentation: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html Start with "Using Flex 4.6" to help you get up to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex MXML has [`Label`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) which would adhere to lifecycle and visual element display list.

Marking the string with the [`Bindable`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html) metadata tag will automatically update the rendered label when the value of the string changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            protected var text:String = "Hello, World!";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label text="{text}" />

</s:Application>
```

Otherwise, you can still use standard [`TextField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) or even [`TLFTextField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html) controls.